# Wso2 iot server Database path?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I'm new on wso2 iot server.

1] I have downloaded wso2 iot server with size approx 700 mb. using windows 10 OS machine.

2] I can use it with android devices. and its working f9

But, **I want to local database storage path which it use to manage all devices, users and other things.**

Answer (score 0):

By default IoTS using H2 database as default DB as same as other WSO2 Products. If you are using IoTS 3.1.0 or it's update version, you can find above DB from here.

```
<IoTS_HOME>/repository/database
```

Further more if you need to know the content of each database and their purpose, please refer [Working With Databases](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Working+with+Databases) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i will check it soon.